# Trying to use subquery to get row count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to substitute subquery results from another table to this query as a column result, each row is getting full table count, not sure how can I get this to work, please advise.

```
SELECT id, name, description, (SELECT count(*)  FROM day WHERE event_id = 1) AS days 
FROM event
```

I've my sql fiddle located at this address.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54697

I need an output like this.

```
id    name    days    
1    'event 1'    3    
2    'event 2'    0
```

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and the results that you want back.

Comment: I just edited with my sample data/expectations, I've the schema built already at sql fiddle link, do you want to write the table strucutre here as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine that you want the number of days for each event.  If so, you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.description,
       (SELECT count(*)  FROM day d WHERE d.event_id = e.id) AS days 
FROM event e;
```

In my opinion, `day` is a lousy name for a table that stores the days when each event is scheduled.  I would expect a table called `day` to have information about days, not events.  You might consider renaming it to `EventDays`.

Comment: Great, it works, going forward, what are the expectations of the community, Is sql fiddle enough or should I explain all the tables first in my question, please have a look at sql fiddle as well

Comment: @user3610227 . . . Your SQL Fiddle is really great.  The issue with the question was simply that the results you want are unclear.  In general, the best question have sample data and desired results, with an explanation, and either SQL code or a SQL fiddle.  I'm sure *you* know what you were asking.  The sample results make it much clearer what you really want (the only problem now is that the SQL Fiddle doesn't have data for event 2).

Comment: @user3610227 both would be nice. full explanation in the question, as well as table schema and expected results - because sqlfiddle is unreliable, with an sqlfiddle link because its damn handy and saves anyone else a bit of time recreating your scenario - shows effort and gumption!

Comment: ok, noted, as an example is it good enough the way I've done the sample data in my question, or appreciate any question with some sample data, as I don't know how would you write tabular data in SO, I've put spaces manually between the columns.

Comment: about the table name, I can't change as I inherited and there are other code dependencies outside my scope of work